# Как регулярным выражением получить часть url?

Tags: php

Получаю часть url после слеша так

```
if (!preg_match('/^([0-9]+)/i', $url, $url_params)) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Данный вариант работает если урл имеет цифровые значения, например, site.ru/123456/789

Чем заменить `([0-9]+)`, чтобы получить часть буквенного url, например,
site.ru/**qwer**-dhfjf-dbjs?

Получить нужно только **qwer**

Спасибо!

Comment: Если до первого пробела и только латиница, то `\w+`.

Comment: так не работает `    if (!preg_match('/^(\w+)/i', $url, $url_params)) {
`

Comment: Замените `^` на `\/`, тогда будет искать совпадение не от начала строки, а от `\/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Получить часть буквенного url, например: site.ru/**qwer**-dhfjf-dbjs*

Находите в строке слэш `/`, и получаете все последующие буквенные символы, до первого не буквенного символа: `'~/\pL+~'`.

Справедливости ради нужно сказать, что этот шаблон сработает только для не полного url, а например для такого *https://site.ru/qwer-dhfjf-dbjs* будет найдена подстрока *site*.

Если необходимо учитывать в ссылках протокол, тогда шаблон можно записать следующим образом: [`'~(?://)?[^/]+/\K\pL+~'`](https://regex101.com/r/bMKwHx/1/)

```
$url = 'https://site.ru/qwer-dhfjf-dbjs';

if (! preg_match('~(?://)?[^/]+/\K\pL+~', $url)) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```